# Get Emacs Markdown markdown mode to use Rstudio pandoc

Tags: init-file, markdown-mode, pandoc

I installed markdown mode for Emacs.  Now I need it to see a version Pandoc I have on my machine.

[Markdown Mode for Emacs](https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/)

I put this in my init file and loaded it.

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(markdown-command "C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\pandoc\pandoc.exe"))
```

Of course the `\` are escape characters, so that does not work.  There is also the issue of the space in the name.

I could ask IT to install Pandoc on my system, but it is already there in the Rstudio directory.

## Update

I tried your suggestion:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

(custom-set-variables
'(markdown-command "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc.exe")) ;; you can also set full path of markdown comman
```

seems to work.  I have a hard time believing that, but I got n `*eww*` loaded correctly.

Comment: What version of emacs are you using (Cygwin, NTEmacs...)? `markdown-mode` uses `(shell-command-on-region... (concat markdown-command " " (shell-quote-argument buffer-file-name))`. You could try to use / instead of \ in the command name. Furthermore you could also try to wrap the command name with double-quotes: `"\"C:/Program.../pandoc.exe\""` Alternatively, you can try to escape the spaces by \\, i.e. `"C:/Program\\ Files/.."` That would work with Cygwin-Bash.

Comment: I am using GNU Emacs